# How to convert iterators of different types

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have a legacy function `Foo` which takes two iterators as input and I want to reuse it but should not change its interface (although I can change the type of iterators but can't make it template)
The problem is that I have iterators of different type and have to copy initial container to get iterators needed for `Foo` function
I was wondering is there any way to convert iterators of one type to iterators of another type?
I tried to use `boost::make_transform_iterator` but it won't compile saying iterators are of different types
Is it possible to uncomment and use the `option 2` (see code below)?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

/* Method with fixed interface */
void Foo(std::vector<int>::const_iterator beginIt, std::vector<int>::const_iterator endIt)
{
    std::cout << "ints:" << std::endl;
    std::copy(beginIt, endIt, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::string> strings { "2", "4", "6" };
    auto convertStringToInt = [](const std::string & s) { return std::stoi(s); };

    // 1) Works, but creates another container with size of initial container
    std::vector<int> convertedInts;
    std::transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::back_inserter(convertedInts), convertStringToInt);
    Foo(convertedInts.begin(), convertedInts.end());

    // 2) Doesn't compile, but operates only with iterators hence there's minimum overhead
    //auto beg = boost::make_transform_iterator(strings.begin(), convertStringToInt);
    //auto end = boost::make_transform_iterator(strings.end(), convertStringToInt);
    //Foo(beg, end);

    std::cout << "strings:" << std::endl;
    std::copy(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

The code can be compiled in online-compiler [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) (it doesn't have a "share" feature)

**Edit:** `Foo` implements logic strictly specific for `int`'s so it's not possible to make it generic. But I have a container (of `std::string`'s as in example) elements of which I can convert to ints via non-capturing lambda.
It seems very odd that there no standard way to wrap one iterator into another :)

Comment: The function takes two data types. That's it. This cannot be changed. You cannot pass any other data type as parameters to this function. C++ does not work in any other way.

Comment: `Foo` only needs iterator-to-(assignable-to-)int. There are infinitely many types types that it could accept. Being a template doesn't mean it has to work for *all* types, just the types it is used with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type-erase the input, e.g. using [`boost::any_range<int>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html) (or it's `iterator` type).

Answer (score 3):

You can template it:

```
template<typename some_iterator>
void Foo(some_iterator beginIt, some_iterator endIt)
{
    ...
}
```

Or the more strict version

```
template<typename some_container>
void Foo(typename some_container::const_iterator beginIt,
         typename some_container::const_iterator endIt)
{
    ...
}
```

If you are using C++11 you can create an even more strict version using `static_assert`

```
template<typename some_container>
void Foo(typename some_container::const_iterator beginIt,
         typename some_container::const_iterator endIt) 
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename some_container::value_type, int>,
        "Only integer containers are accepted");
    ...
}
```

Or using `enable_if`

```
template<typename some_container>
auto Foo(typename some_container::const_iterator beginIt,
         typename some_container::const_iterator endIt) ->
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<
             typename some_container::value_type,int>, void>::type
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I should've mentioned that the function is implemented for concrete type and cannot be made template, sorry about that

Comment: Please edit your original question to include this information and provide your reasoning for why you can't template it.

Comment: You can template it and still assume that the type is int. calls with types other than int will just fail to compile.

Comment: In any case, I've added some more options using C++11

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. `vector::const_iterator` is basically just a glorified raw pointer, and there's no way to hook any functionality into dereferencing a raw pointer.

You'll have to accept the overhead if you can't change the function signature.

Comment: thanks, but I should've mentioned that the function is implemented for concrete type and cannot be made template

Comment: I understand that. Did you read my answer? Like I said, this isn't possible since you can't change the function signature.